# Equivalência entre EXCEPT | INTERSECT & exists | not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

Seria o `EXCEPT | INTERSECT` sempre equivalente a um `not exists | exists`?

Tendo a seguinte consulta

```
SELECT ProductID   
FROM Production.Product  
INTERSECT  
SELECT ProductID   
FROM Production.WorkOrder
```

Poderia escrever da seguinte forma

```
SELECT ProductID   
FROM Production.Product a
where exists (
    SELECT NULL   
    FROM Production.WorkOrder b where a.ProductID = b.ProductID)
```

E teria o mesmo resultado?

Em termos de performance entre as duas consultas, qual teria uma melhor performance? Usando o `exists`? ou Usando o `INTERSECT`?

Em que situações eu não poderia substituir o `EXCEPT | INTERSECT` por `not exists | exists` ou o contrário?

Comment: `EXCEPT` e `INTERSECT` faz um union de dois select com uma ação a ser executada.(retorna linhas distintas ou não). O `exists` apenas verifica se a subquery é verdadeira ou falsa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A questão de performance depende de vários fatores, como informação a ser retornada, presença de índices que facilitem o processamento das consultas,  estatísticas existentes e atualizadas, características dos dados etc. Afora a ação do otimizador de consultas, que pode gerar planos de execução semelhantes (ou até mesmo idênticos) para construções SQL diferentes.

As consultas que constam na pergunta são para o banco de dados Adventure Works. Ao executar as duas em um mesmo ambiente, observa-se que o mesmo plano de execução foi gerado para as duas consultas.

[image: Planos de execução para as duas consultas]

Entretanto, isto não significa que sejam construções semelhantes. Nos códigos postados na pergunta foi possível utilizar INTERSECT para resolver uma das  consultas porque somente a coluna ProductID é retornada. Entretanto, caso seja necessário retornar alguma outra coluna da tabela Production.Product que não tenha equivalência na tabela Production.WorkOrder, não será possível o uso do INTERSECT.

Por exemplo, se além do código do produto for necessário retornar também o nome do produto, como no código abaixo

```
-- código #3
SELECT ProductID, Name 
FROM Production.Product a
where exists (
    SELECT NULL   
    FROM Production.WorkOrder b where a.ProductID = b.ProductID);
```

não haverá como obter o mesmo resultado utilizando o INTERSECT.

```
-- código #4
SELECT ProductID, Name  
FROM Production.Product  
INTERSECT  
SELECT ProductID   
FROM Production.WorkOrder;
```

sendo que o seguinte erro é exibido ao executar o código #4:

Mensagem 205, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 2
Todas as consultas combinadas que usam o operador UNION, INTERSECT ou EXCEPT devem ter um número igual de expressões em suas listas de destino.